# Android ExpandableListView bug

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have the folowing listener and I override the method `onGroupExpand`:

```
list.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() { 

            @Override 
            public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) { 
                long groupId = adapter.getGroupId(groupPosition);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Group =  " + adapter.getGroupId(groupPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d(TAG, "Group expanded");
                View v = adapter.getGroupView((int) groupId, true, null, list);

                TextView txt = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.expandable_first_layer);
                Log.d(TAG, "txt: " + txt.getText());
                txt.setText("Tru-ru-ru");
                Log.d(TAG, "txt: " + txt.getText());
            } 
        });
```

I see the proper text when I invoke  `txt.getText()` first time. Then and after second  `txt.getText()` in my LogCat I see new text.

But the point is that `ExpandableListView` doesn't change it's text in that particular item. The same with setting background color in onGroupExpand. Has anybody encountered with this bug?

Comment: You have to notifydatasetchange to refresh the expandablelist after making any changes to the list.

Comment: No, adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() doesn`t solve the problem.

Comment: i dnt understand why are you trying to set the text when u expand the list

Comment: it would be better if u could try to explain what u r trying to do. cos i guess you are using the wrong listener to do it

Comment: Actually, I'm trying to change color of group listItem when it`s expanded. It doesn't work now. Changing text is easy for testig, that's why I use it.

Comment: u can differentiate the group list and the child list separately by specifying different color in the adapter itself

Comment: R u trying to change the color when that particular row in group is clicked

Comment: yes! you are right! I want to change color of row when it is expanded. (Group row)

Comment: can u say r u using inflated listview

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your adapter class in the getGroupView method check the state of the list ie if expanded or collapse in if condition, if its expanded you can set different colour..
Check the snippet below for more information

```
public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, final boolean isExpanded, 
            View convertView, ViewGroup parentView)
    {

            convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.red);
            if(isExpanded){

            convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.blue);

            }





        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: I don`t know. Whan I`m copying this to adapter, I have NullPointerException where convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.red);  (color is available)

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to get convertview by inflating proper layout,else it will give the exception